# Resistance as reference in impedance triangle

Tags: impedance

Why Resistance is taken as reference in impedance triangle of RL series circuit, why not reactance as reference ?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not mandatory that R should be the reference. Tilt your head sideways to make \$X_L \$ the reference vector.

[image]

Hope you got the point.

Comment: How phasor diagram looks like if R has a phase angle of 20 degrees with respect to reference vector XL.

Answer (score 0):

Resistance is used as the reference because voltage and current are in phase for that device.

Comment: In voltage triangle, current is taken as reference since same current flows through resistance and inductance. So, current will be same across resistance and inductance. Hence current is taken as reference in voltage triangle. In the same way, what is the reason behind taking resistance as reference in impedance triangle ?